# Fail in calling a Fortran subroutine from R

Tags: r, fortran, call, subroutine

I tried to call a simple Fortran subroutine from R but something get wrong. I managed to compile the Fortran code (I precise that I'm only a beginner in this language) but the fail happens when I call the subroutine in R.

The Fortran code is a simple subroutine which compute the value of a fonction at each point of an (defined) range. Then the results are stored in a matrix (array in fortran) of size 2x100 000. One row stores the value of the fonction f(x) and the other row stores the corresponding variable (x).

```
Subroutine algo(n, tho, c, phi, ydata, eps, results)

    ! n : number of observations
    ! tho : number of steps in the range
    ! phi and c are given parameters 
    ! ydata : the vector of data
    ! eps : the iteration step
    ! results : array which stores the results

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER                                 :: n, i, j, tho
    DOUBLE PRECISION                        :: c, phi, sigma2, eps, ll 
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(1:n)        :: ydata 
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(1:tho)      :: vecteps
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(1:2,1:tho)  :: results
    DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER             :: pi=acos(-1.d0)

    ! vecteps is the vector of all the x 
    vecteps(1)=0

    do i=1,tho
        vecteps(i)=vecteps(i)+eps
    end do

    do j=1,tho
        sigma2=vecteps(j)

        ll=-( (-(n-1)/2)*log(2*pi)-((n-1)/2)*log(sigma2)-
        sum((ydata(2:n)-c-phi*ydata(1:n-1))**2)/(2*sigma2) )

        results(1,j)=ll
        results(2,j)=vecteps(j)
    end do

end subroutine algo
```

Then the call from R

```
y=rnorm(200,0,1)
y[1]=4/(1-0.6)
for(i in 2:length(y)){
  y[i]=4+0.6*y[i-1]+rnorm(1,0,1)
}

results=matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=100000)

dyn.load("algo.dll")
    .Fortran('algo',n=as.integer(200), tho=as.integer(100000), c=as.double(4), phi=as.double(0.6), ydata=as.double(y), eps=as.double(0.0001), results=as.double(results) )
```

From the 1000 observations of the array "results" that R gives, the numbers are for the vast majority all the same with few NaN :

```
$results
   [1]  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04
   [7]  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04
  [13]           NaN           NaN  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04  8.921136e+05  1.000000e-04
```

I would like that he gives me an output with [1] f(x1) 0.0001  f(x2) 0.0002  ...

To me, the problem may come from 3 different issues

- wrong maths in the Fortran code
- the incorrect use of the matrix/arrays
- the subroutine call from R ( .Fortran(..., n=as... ) )

but I fail to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have just edited the initial post for greater clarity in the results.

Comment: I've not a computer to check through this, but in the first loop `vecteps(i)=vecteps(i)+eps` looks very suspicious: to that point only `vecteps(1)` has been defined.  Perhaps you mean `vecteps=0` (or `vecteps(:)=0`), although neither makes much sense to me given the loop afterwards?

Comment: With this loop i try to generate a vector which would be similar to a vector create by this R code : "vecteps=seq(from=0.0001, to=10, by=0.0001)"... but you are right, it seems to fail here.

Comment: [This question's​ answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23245371) have examples of how to create/construct such an array in Fortran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [inline](https://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package -- here is its first example:

```
R> x <- as.numeric(1:10)
R> n <- as.integer(10)
R> code <- "
+       integer i
+       do 1 i=1, n(1)
+     1 x(i) = x(i)**3
+ "
R> cubefn <- cfunction(signature(n="integer", x="numeric"), code, 
+                      convention=".Fortran")
R> print(cubefn)
An object of class 'CFunc'
function (n, x) 
.Primitive(".Fortran")(<pointer: 0x7fc8a8db7660>, n = as.integer(n), 
    x = as.double(x))
<environment: 0x8193e98>
code:
  1: 
  2:        SUBROUTINE file2e6b876b50a29 ( n, x )
  3:       INTEGER n(*)
  4:       DOUBLE PRECISION x(*)
  5: 
  6:       integer i
  7:       do 1 i=1, n(1)
  8:     1 x(i) = x(i)**3
  9: 
 10:       RETURN
 11:       END
 12: 
R> cubefn(n, x)$x
 [1]    1    8   27   64  125  216  343  512  729 1000
R>
```

I would use this to make sure your code builds and runs, and once that is accomplished, suggest to create a package.